# Google Plus Sign-in Button is not rendered & triggered properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, google-plus

I need to integrete Google plus sign in button. I'm using angularjs directive ([angular-directive.g-signin](http://console.developers.google.com)

1. Created Google API ID.
2. Added `google-plus-signin.js` through bower.
3. Added `directive.g+signin` as a dependency.
4. Create a login controller and added these methods.
   'event:google-plus-signin-success' & 'event:google-plus-signin-failure'
5. Updated CSS file.
6. Finally added these code snippet into the html file.

```html
<div ng-controller="LoginController">
  <google-plus-signin clientid="API-ID"  customtargetid="my-custom-element">
      <div id="googlebutton"><button>Sign In With Google</button></div>
  </google-plus-signin>
          <p>^ This is a Google Plus sign-in button</p>
</div>
```

It doesn't render google plus logo anyway there is a button. And when I click on the button it didn't popup google plus sign in window.

Anything missing or any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Installed `google-plus-signin.js` through bower. The problem is this file is not latest one.Then I manually copy & paste the `google-plus-signin.js`. Now it's working fine.